# How can i get the password show and hide option for an existing char field in xml for odoo 8 framework is it possible by using some widgets

Tags: python, xml, odoo

**I have added the java script in the xml file  and added widget in the smtp_pass field.**

```
<group string="Security and Authentication" colspan="4">
<field name="smtp_encryption" on_change="on_change_encryption(smtp_encryption)"/>
<script>
    openerp.MODULE_NAME = function (instance) {
        instance.MODULE_NAME.Password = instance.web.form.FieldChar.extend({
            events: {
                "click .password": "toggle_password",
            },

            initialize_content: function() {
              this.setupFocus(this.$('input'));
              this.$('input').parent().append('&lt;i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye password" style="position: relative;margin-bottom: 0px;bottom: 20px;left: 90%;"/>');
            },

            toggle_password: function() {
                var node = this.$('input');
                if (node.attr('type') === 'password') {
                    node.prop('type', 'text');
                    $('i').toggleClass("fa-eye-slash");
                } else {
                    node.prop('type', 'password');
                    $('i').removeClass('fa-eye-slash')
                }
            },
        });

        instance.web.form.widgets.add('password', 'instance.MODULE_NAME.Password');
    };
</script>
<field name="smtp_user"/>
<field name="smtp_pass" password="True" widget='password'/>
```

**And in python file i added the related field for smtp_pass**

```
'smtp_pass': fields.char('Password',size=64, help="Optional password for SMTP authentication"),
'related_smtp_pass':fields.char(related='smtp_pass'),
```

Comment: Please help us answer your question by showing some code, state what you have tried already, what doesn't work and your error messages if you get any. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Using a field several times on the form view is not supported in Odoo 8.

You can add a related field to `smtp_password` and use it to show the password.

```py
related_smtp_password = fields.Char(related='smtp_password')
```

It is not possible to set the [password](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js#L2295) attribute with conditions.

The char field is handled by the client widget, you can customize the behavior of the char field using the javascript.

You can extend the char widget and create a new one with an eye to the right corner to show or hide the password, you can try the following example:

```js
openerp.MODULE_NAME = function (instance) {
    instance.MODULE_NAME.Password = instance.web.form.FieldChar.extend({
        events: {
            "click .password": "toggle_password",
        },

        initialize_content: function() {
            this.setupFocus(this.$('input'));
            this.$('input').parent().append('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-eye password" style="position: relative;margin-bottom: 0px;bottom: 20px;left: 90%;"/>');
        },

        toggle_password: function() {
            var node = this.$('input');
            if (node.attr('type') === 'password') {
                node.prop('type', 'text');
                $('i').toggleClass("fa-eye-slash");
            } else {
                node.prop('type', 'password');
                $('i').removeClass('fa-eye-slash')
            }
        },


    });

    instance.web.form.widgets.add('password', 'instance.MODULE_NAME.Password');
};
```

You have just to use the following declaratio in the form view:

```
<field name="smtp_password" password="True" widget='password'/>
```

***Edit:***

Create an XML file (`templates.xml`) and add the following code:

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="Assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/MODULE_NAME/static/src/js/script.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

And add it to the data in the manifest file (`__openerp__.py`):

```py
'data': [
        'templates.xml',
    ],
```

Then create the js file under `/static/src/js/` and add the above javascript code.

Comment: Thanku but it did not work for me  can you give an another method

Comment: Please update you question. How you checked both methods?

Comment: please find the updated  code above Thanku in advance

Comment: The related field and javascript examples are separated, so you have to choose. Check [Adding static resources css and javascript](https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/adding-static-resources-css-and-javascript-to-odoo/) to add the javascript code.

Comment: Hai should i create an xml file for the javascript to add <template> and <xpath> tags and to add <script>tag path

Comment: You need to add it to the `web.assets_backend`, check my edit.

Comment: Thanku but in the existing xml field smtp_pass we should only add widget=password  like this
 <field name="smtp_pass" password="True" widget='password'/> and in python i have added                                     'related_smtp_pass':fields.char(related='smtp_pass'), below the existing field 'smtp_pass': fields.char('Password',size=64, help="Optional password for SMTP authentication"), but it does not works for me

Comment: Use the related field or the password widget, not both!

Comment: Hi I have tried both renmoving simultaneously one after the another but their is no change occured.I have a doubt that where we have given relation between <field smtp_pass /> in xml and java script code when we declared widget=password how will it call the javascript in static/src folder can you please explain me

Comment: Let try only the javascript solution. I created a [sample module](https://filebin.net/8khz3g4uftal2rk8/password_widget.zip?t=cxht5ith) that adds the password widget, all you have is to set two attributes on a char field: `password="True"` and `widgget="password".`

Comment: Hai case1: while i am trying to enter password and save it it is not taking its showing field is invalid not saving  case2:When i enter password and when i click on the eye icon of password vissibility it is getting saved   In Case 1 it is nnot working  can you suggest changes in javascript code(password widget) above to make password  save in Case1.

Comment: it is not the log error Its showing   Followiing field is invalid

Comment: I checked it with a computed field and a simple char field and it is working as expected. Try to describe exactly how you add that field. When I said the error log it could be found in the javascript console.

Comment: I have placed widget=password in xml and nnot done any changes in python

Comment: Did you change the JavaScript code? If possible reproduce the issue in a demo module.

Comment: I have changed changed javascript in the one line above the else: condition as   
 this.$('i').toggleClass("fa-eye-slash");  i have added this

Comment: It is the same, you did not change it.

Comment: when i keep it as it is it is changing other module icon when i click on that thats why i have kept yhis for referencing the current object

Comment: Please explain how that code is changing other module icon?

Comment: Hai kenly how can we delete records in many2many field can you please help with solution

Comment: It depends on the context, If you need to remove the records from the set without deleting them then use [commands](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/models.py#L3728) `2` or `5`. Use command `2` to remove records from the list then delete them from database or simply call `unlink` on the recordset.

Comment: Thank you kenly should we use the 1,id in write function

Comment: `(1, id, values)` command is used to update an existing record of id with the values.